# In a menus's render array, where are the render arrays for the second-level options?

Tags: 7

I have a render array made by calling `menu_tree_output` on my main menu. The menu contains first-level options, naturally enough, and some of these have second-level children. I need to reformat my menu so that when output by `render` or `drupal_render`, each list of second-level options appears not just as `<ul>` and `<li>` elements, but as a more complicated chunk of HTML containing the links. (These chunks will implement dropdown menus with icons and subgroup headings inserted between and above links.) Reading http://themery.com/book/export/html/100 , "Using the Render API", I thought render arrays would be ideal. I could transform each list and shove the result back into the render array as raw markup. However, I'm having trouble finding the render arrays that represent the second-level menu options.

Putting my problem in more abstract terms, I've got a menu render array holding a list of lists *L<sub>i</sub>*. Each *L<sub>i</sub>* is a `<ul>` containing `<li>` and `<a>` elements. In the render array, I want to replace each *L<sub>i</sub>* by *f( L<sub>i</sub> )*, where *f* is a PHP function that I'll implement. It will insert HTML between *L<sub>i</sub>*'s elements and around them.

I started by doing

```
  $tree = menu_tree_all_data( 'main-menu' );
  $options = menu_tree_output( $tree );
```

The second line is because, as explained in https://groups.drupal.org/node/145064 , "Geek question - Why is there no render array for links in D7?", menus are not render arrays, and need to be converted to such.

So `$options` is a render array. I first tested that I understood its structure well enough to loop over it and print the first- and second-level options. Here's my code:

```
  foreach ( $options as $option ) {
    $title = $option[ '#title' ]; 
    if ( strlen( $title ) != 0 ) {
      print $title . '<BR>';
      $sub_options = $option[ '#below' ];
      if ( count( $sub_options ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $sub_options as $sub_option ) {
          $sub_title = $sub_option[ '#title' ]; 
          if ( strlen( $sub_title ) != 0 ) 
            print '&nbsp;&nbsp' . $sub_title . '<BR>';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This seems to work, displaying the list:

```
  OPTION 1
  OPTION 2
    Sub-option 2.1
    Sub-option 2.2
  OPTION 3
    Sub-option 3.1
```

(The above are the names of my test options — not very interesting, I know.)

A problem I had when writing the code is that I couldn't find a spec of exactly what a menu's render array has in it. But from `dpm` and the source of `menu_tree_output`, I gathered that an option's name is in its `#title` element, and that its sub-options are in its `#below` element, which is an array.

Actually, that wasn't quite enough. Some options had empty titles which I had to skip: hence my tests on the length of `$title` and `$sub_title`. But I seemed to be going in the right direction, so I then tried another loop. This one was intended, just as a proof of concept, to add a prefix and a suffix to each list of options: both the first-level list and the second-level lists.

Here's that code:

```
  foreach ( $options as $option ) {
    $title = $option[ '#title' ]; 
    if ( strlen( $title ) != 0 ) { 
      $sub_options = $option[ '#below' ];
      if ( count( $sub_options ) > 0 ) {
        $sub_options[ '#prefix' ] = 'Level 2 prefix';
        $sub_options[ '#suffix' ] = 'Level 2 suffix';
      }
    }
  }
  $options[ "#prefix" ] = "Level 1 prefix";
  $options[ "#suffix" ] = "Level 1 suffix";
  print( drupal_render( $options ) );
```

Apparently, it's a feature of all render arrays that if you set their `#prefix` and `#suffix` elements and then render and display them, you'll see the prefix appear before the output and the suffix after it. So I thought this would be a good test. The first-level prefix and suffix do indeed appear, enclosing the menu itself.

But the second-level ones don't. Why? The source of `menu_tree_output` contains the line

```
$element['#below'] = $data['below'] ? menu_tree_output($data['below']) : $data['below'];
```

which certainly looks as though the `#below` elements should become render arrays. So why aren't `#prefix` and `#suffix` working on them?

By the way, I clear my cache before each test with `drush cc all`. If it matters. And my code is running in a `page.tpl.php` which I've written from scratch as part of a new theme. So there shouldn't be any interference from an existing theme.

Comment: PHP is (ostensibly) pass-by-value unless you're throwing an object into the mix. So, assuming you're trying to make changes to the original `$options` array before rendering it, `foreach ( $options as $option ) {` needs to be `foreach ( $options as &$option ) {`, and `$sub_options = $option[ '#below' ];` needs to be `$sub_options = &$option[ '#below' ];`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. Now to see whether I can replace the lists by markup generated from them.

Answer (score 1):

As Clive pointed out, I should have assigned my sub-arrays by reference. So my code should have been:

```
  foreach ( $options as &$option ) {
      $title = $option[ '#title' ]; 
      if ( strlen( $title ) != 0 ) { 
        $sub_options = &$option[ '#below' ];
        if ( count( $sub_options ) > 0 ) {
          $sub_options[ '#prefix' ] = 'Level 2 prefix';
          $sub_options[ '#suffix' ] = 'Level 2 suffix';
        }
      }
    }
    $options[ "#prefix" ] = "Level 1 prefix";
    $options[ "#suffix" ] = "Level 1 suffix";
    print( drupal_render( $options ) );
```

That worked, printing the first- and the second-level prefix and suffix.

Armed with the knowledge that I was on the right track, I modified my code as below. Each loop cycle renders one list of sub-options and stores the resulting HTML. It then encloses it in a <table> tag, just as a demo. And it then puts the result back as raw markup. Rendering the entire menu will then display that markup, so that all my sub-options are enclosed in a table border and headed with a caption. In real life, they'd be a hidden div which reveals when you hover over it, displaying a fancy sub-menu.

One subtlety is that I had to call `show`, because the line `$rendered_sub_options = drupal_render( $sub_options );` flags those sub-options as already printed, so that the final call to `render` would ignore them unless I unset the flag.

```
  foreach ( $options as &$option ) {
    $title = $option[ '#title' ]; 
    if ( strlen( $title ) != 0 ) { 
      $sub_options = &$option[ '#below' ];
      if ( count( $sub_options ) > 0 ) {
        $rendered_sub_options = drupal_render( $sub_options ); 
        $rendered_sub_options = entable( $rendered_sub_options ); 
        show( $sub_options );
        $sub_options[ '#markup' ] = $rendered_sub_options;
        $sub_options[ '#type' ] = 'markup';
      }
    }
  }

  function entable( $html )
  {
    return "<table border=1>" .
           "<tr><td>SUB-OPTIONS</td></tr>" .
           "<tr><td>$html</td></tr>" .
           "</table>" ;
  }

  print( drupal_render( $options ) );
```